# Ubuntu 10.04 freezing randomly and completelty

Tags: freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I have problem with my Ubuntu 10.04 that installed on Lenovo T420 laptop.
it keep freezing randomly and i don't know how to fix it.

when it freeze, it freeze completely and the only way is to hold power button till poweroff then power it back on. dyas it's working fine then suddenly
freeze.

can any one please assist me to resolve this problem, my system is 2 years and it's business used.

thanks alot.

Comment: Do you have a swap partition? Have you tried running a memory test? Also, after the freeze, can you power it down, start it up again, and include the contents of `/var/log/dmesg` by opening it in a text editor and pasting it on paste.ubuntu.com, then giving a link?(Gave wrong link first time)

Comment: Hello ObsessiveFOSS, thanks for your respond. i don't run the test and i'm going to do it now. i paste the output of dmesg. my system hang between date 2 and 3 of Aug (yesterday) the link is there: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1127052/     i will do the memory test and post back. thanks alot

Comment: just to note that, i have a swap partition and it's only 100MB, could this make any problem. my RAM is 4G but i'm using PAE kernel thus i got 3.8G since i'm using x32 not x64.

Comment: You'll want 4-6 GB. If you don't have space for a new partition, you can [create a swap file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/).

Comment: this will create new swap space, can i increase my current partition safely without losing data. thanks alot for your help and support.

Comment: The method in the link creates a new file. It doesn't change your partitions.

Comment: Thanks alot ObsessiveFOSS, i will post back the Memory test result once done. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello, the result to memory test is no error, i already increased the swap disk to 3G. my system is freeze today as well at this time(4 AUG 16:27) but i don't see any log that tell what is cases of this freez, i attached both logs, dmesg and kernel. could you please help me to fix this freezes issue. thanks alot. dmesg [http://paste.ubuntu.com/1129523/] Kernel log [http://paste.ubuntu.com/1129526/]

Comment: Your paste links had the wrong syntax: here are the correct links: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1129523/ and http://paste.ubuntu.com/1129526/

Comment: Hi ObsessiveFOSS, thanks for your correction. do you have any other tips that might help me fix this problem. would be appreciated.

Comment: Could any one help me please on this or provide any tips.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have much experience in this field, but I will post this question on chat.

Comment: thanks alot ObsessiveFOSS, any help will be so appreciated. really i like this system just need to fix it.